# Combobox Telerik - change color

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm using the combobox control:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/ComboBox?theme=vista

And I want it to be not white, like it is now. Which css property can do this? Is it possible?

I want it to look like this:

[image: combo box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that with a custom background color on the select element and some rounded corners on its container. Try placing the combobox in a containing DIV and give it these CSS styles:

```
.rounded {
    border-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    padding: 5px;
    background: #333;
}

.rounded select {
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff; 
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mpHgR/1/

It might be a little off, but it's close to what you want.

Comment: I was not asking about the rounded corners, but about the color.